# autoincrementation of selected dependent fields in the table Sql-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

**Problem:**

Is it possible to auto-complete the "help" column (automatically, without human intervention)?

if (Login = 'MIPA' AND 'int' in 'Number' is > 7 (greater than 7) )  **| CONDITION**

**then:**

smallest line with FolderID (varchar)

get the value 1, and each subsequent one is to get the value i = 1, i ++ (i.e. 1 greater than the previous one, i.e. 2, 3.4, etc.)

```
   Type    | Name
-----------+-------
varchar(31)| FolderId
varchar(31)| Login 
   int     | Number
   int     | Help


FolderId| Login | Number|  Help
-------+-------+-------+-----
   1   | MIPA  |   1   |  NULL
   4   | MIPA  |   8   |  NULL
   7   | MIPA  |   8   |  NULL
   9   | MIPA  |   3   |  NULL
...
  15   | MIPA  |   8   |  NULL
...
 121   | RODO  |   1   |  NULL
 124   | RODO  |   8   |  NULL
 127   | RODO  |   8   |  NULL
 129   | RODO  |   3   |  NULL
...
1215   | RODO  |   1   |  NULL
```

So finally it would look like this:

```
   Type    | Name
-----------+-------
varchar(31)| FolderId
varchar(31)| Login 
   int     | Number
   int     | Help


FolderId| Login | Number|  Help
-------+-------+-------+-----
   1   | MIPA  |   1   |  NULL
   4   | MIPA  |   8   |  1
   7   | MIPA  |   8   |  2
   9   | MIPA  |   3   |  NULL
...
  15   | MIPA  |   8   |  3
...
 121   | RODO  |   1   |  NULL
 124   | RODO  |   8   |  NULL
 127   | RODO  |   8   |  NULL
 129   | RODO  |   3   |  NULL
...
1215   | RODO  |   1   |  NULL
```

What I did?

I have never sat in databases reworking their scripts, so I don't know if such an operation is possible at all

I use Managment Studio 2018

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate this as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when login = 'MIPA' and Number > 7
             then row_number() over (partition by login, (case when number > 7 then 1 else 0 end)
                                     FolderId
                                    )
        end) as new_help
from t;
```

If you want to update the value, use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by login order by FolderId) as new_help
      from t
      where login = 'MIPA' and number > 7
     )
update toupdate
    set help = new_help;
```